# How do I resolve this memory allocation issue when using structs?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

My program consists of reading a file of acronyms and their associated definitions, then allowing the user to find a definition based on the acronym they entered.

e.g. the user enters FAT, the program prints out "file allocation table", and whatever other definitions are mapped to FAT.

The way the definitions are intended to be stored is using a linked list.
The acronyms as an array of structs.
The issue I am running into is when I try and malloc space for a struct object.

There are no compiler warnings/errors, but when I step through the code, always at this point:

```
AcronymDB * entry_list = malloc( sizeof( AcronymDB ) );
```

The following error is shown in the Variables view window:

```
_entry_list AcronymDB * Error: Multiple errors reported.
Failed to execute MI command: -var-update 1 var3 Error message from debugger back end: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf00d
Failed to execute MI command: -var-update 1 var3 Error message from debugger back end: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf00d_
```

That memory address `0xbaadf00d` (third line) appears to be the same regardless of how many times I run the program, or open/close it. I don't understand why that is happening.

I am using Portable Eclipse

**Edit:** **rows** is a global variable for the total amount of entries counted previously, **r** is the current row that the acronym was found in.

These are the structs, and the problem appears to be with the last one.

```
//associated definitions in a linked list
typedef struct defnList
{
    char * defn;
    struct defnList * next;
} Definition;

//acronym entry
typedef struct
{
    char * acronym;
    Definition * f_defn;     //a pointer to the first definition
} Acronym;

//database of acronyms
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int entries;
    Acronym ** acronyms;     //array of pointers to acronym entries
} AcronymDB;
```

This is the function call where the issue happens.
**delimbuff** is an output from strtok, e.g. an acronym string being passed, **r** is the current row of the acronym entry, in my case it's the very first one, so **r** is 0.
I haven't implemented any error handling yet.

```
void addAcronym( char * delimbuff, unsigned int r )
{
    //this is where the problem occurs
    AcronymDB * entry_list = malloc( sizeof( AcronymDB ) );
    if ( entry_list == NULL )
    {

    }

    entry_list -> acronyms = malloc( sizeof( Acronym * ) * rows  );
    if ( entry_list -> acronyms == NULL )
    {
        free( entry_list );
    }
    entry_list -> acronyms[ r ] = malloc( sizeof( Acronym ) );
    entry_list -> acronyms[ r ] -> acronym = strdup( delimbuff );
}
```

My expectation is even if there is a memory allocation issue, then the next line with the if statement would capture it, but it doesn't, and the code continues executing until the function ends, and then some more.

Comment: The issue is most probably that you corrupt the bookkeeping info beyond the allocated object

Comment: @user3121023 - sorry, I have now edited the post. rows is a global variable for the total amount of entries found. r is the current row/entry being worked on.

Comment: The error is in a part of the code you have not posted. See [mcve].

Comment: OK, I will clean up the code and then post it. Apologies for not posting it earlier, the guide said not to post it all.

It appears that memory address 0xbadf00d has some significance, and I'm accessing some memory that I am not meant to.

Comment: In the short code you posted, you should at least add `assert(r < rows)` check or similar. Are you sure `r` is lower then `rows`? And you are missing a check from malloc return, consider also adding `assert(entry_list->acronyms[r] != NULL)`. Note that it's standard /common to represent count of elements using `size_t` type.

Comment: That error looks like it's from the debugger, not your executable. Are you able to run a simple program which calls `malloc` like `void main(void) { void *a = malloc(16); }`?

Comment: @KamilCuk - thanks for the tips, will look into it. As mentioned earlier though, error handling is not really implemented as I'm looking into the issue mentioned. The error doesn't have anything to do with r or rows, or at least I don't think it does, it's during the malloc for the struct object.

Comment: @Tim - yes it seems probable that it could be related to the debbugger. I ran the code you suggested and there's no issue. I can see in Debug view that it allocates it at some random address.

There are plenty of other mallocs going on elsewhere in the code, and no issues there either.

Comment: @Tim - you are right, it is indeed related to the debugger. It appears there was no real issue, at least not with the suspect code I thought was causing trouble. That 0xbaadf00d address is a Windows memory pattern for uninitialised memory that was allocated as a result of a call to malloc.

I had to do a bit of reading on this.

I could initialise and write to the memory later, and the debugger showed the correct values were in place. But based on your comment, I decided to just printf the results and regardless of the supposed "error" - the values were coming out fine.

Comment: regarding: `entry_list -> acronyms = malloc( sizeof( Acronym * ) * rows  );
    if ( entry_list -> acronyms == NULL )
    {
        free( entry_list );
    }`  probably unable to 'free()' something that failed to be allocated.. However, the function: `free()` properly handles a parameter containing: `NULL`

Comment: regarding: `if ( entry_list == NULL )` and `if ( entry_list -> acronyms == NULL )`  When handling such an error, first call `perror( "malloc failed" );` then after cleaning up (calls to `free()`) need to call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` to exit the program

Comment: the code should be checking the result of EVERY call to `malloc()` and every call to `strdup()` to assure the operation was successful

Comment: OT: most debuggers use the struct `tag` name for displaying the fields within a struct.  Such a `tag` name costs you nothing and greatly helps when debugging

Comment: @user3629249 - what do you mean by a 'tag' name? This sounds useful but I am not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: @user3629249 - not sure what you mean by unable to free something that failed to be allocated. I am freeing the allocation for 'entry_list' if the allocation for 'entry_list -> acronyms' fails. They aren't the same thing. And I hadn't done the error handling at that point yet, but yes, what you mentioned is effectively what I've done.

Comment: example of a 'tag' name:  `struct tagname { .... };`